# Getting right column to show up on top of left column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have two columns. Desktop:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

This is expected behavior, but I want the column on the left "Browse Programs" to show up on top of the left column, not below it.  I've tried a few different things, including reversing the order of columns in HTML and using "float-left" (which works, but not a great solution).  I've also used `col-md-pull` and `col-md-push` but neither is working.

For what it's worth, I'm not using bootstraps 4 and I'd prefer to keep that as is for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Place the blocks inside the layout in the order in which they should go on the mobile.

   > [Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag): Bootstrap is developed mobile first, a strategy in which we optimize code for mobile devices first and then scale up components as necessary using CSS media queries.
2. Change their order. To do this, Bootstrap 3 [provides classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-column-ordering) of the type `.col-md-push-9` and `.col-md-pull-3`, and Bootstrap 4 provides [the order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#order-classes).

Demo for Bootstrap 3: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/qBONaQd

```css
/* Demo Decorations */
.row-demo > div {
 color: white;
 font: bold 20px sans-serif;
 padding: 9px 15px 30px;
}
.row-demo > div:first-child {
 background: #69c;
}
.row-demo > div:last-child {
 background: #c69;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row row-demo">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">Top on mobile / Right on desktop</div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">Bottom on mobile / Left on desktop</div>
 </div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Demo for Bootstrap 4: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/GRpZVZq

```css
/* Demo Decorations */
.row-demo > div {
 color: white;
 font: bold 20px sans-serif;
 padding: 9px 15px 30px;
}
.row-demo > div:first-child {
 background: #69c;
}
.row-demo > div:last-child {
 background: #c69;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row row-demo">
  <div class="col-md-3 order-md-last">Top on mobile / Right on desktop</div>
  <div class="col-md-9 order-md-first">Bottom on mobile / Left on desktop</div>
 </div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: how about a solution that doesn't use bootstraps 4?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 Is the "bootstrap-4" tag in your question wrong? Do you use Bootstrap 3?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 I've added a solution for Bootstrap 3 into my answer. If you are already using the solutions out of the box and they do not work, then add your code to the question so that it can be verified.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 The answer contains two solutions. The first is the solution for Bootsrap 3. It uses the stylesheet of Bootsrap 3.4.1 and uses the classes from the Bootsrap 3.4 documentation. Check, please.

Comment: works.  Thank you!  I hope bootstraps 3 works for a while.  I find it easier to use than 4.  When I used bootstraps 4 framework, it changed the whole layout of my website.